# php variable to javascript (via json)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I know this has been discussed before but I can't seem to make anything work. I'm trying to pass the variable `$thedate` from PHP file `mainclass.php` to the variable `datestr` in a JS function from the file `footer_script.php`

JS:

```
function getsched(str)
{
    //some code
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mainclass.php',
        data: 'date=' + str + '&form=getsched',
        success: function(data) {
            var datestr = <?php echo json_encode($thedate); ?>;
            $("#" + str).html(data);
        }
    }).error(function() {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
case "getsched":
    //some code
    //some query

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        //more code
        $thedate = $_POST['date'];
    }
    //other code here
break;
```

When I alert `datestr`, I get `undefined`. How to fix this?

Comment: You should learn about the difference between front-end and back-end.

Comment: how are you outputting a response to the POST request? You've failed to show that - oh, wait, I see now. You think PHP <--> HTML forms some sort of bi-directional link that you can communicate through ... simply, that's not how PHP works

Comment: You can't use PHP like this. You should obtain the response from PHP and use it.

Comment: yes, I noticed that - @AniketSahrawat - which is clearly incorrect of course :p

Comment: thank you for the inputs im actually still in the process of learning the language and json is something im trying out just now so please bear with me

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PHP like this. You should obtain the response from PHP and use it. In your PHP, you should output a response similar to this (just an example of JSON response):

```
echo json_encode(array('thedate', '2018-4-3'));
```

and you can obtain the value of `2018-4-3` in your JS with:

```
function getsched(str)
{
    //some code
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mainclass.php',
        data: 'date=' + str + '&form=getsched',
        success: function(data) {
            var datestr = data.thedate;
            $("#" + str).html(datastr);
        }
    }).error(function() {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the line:

```
var datestr = <?php echo json_encode($thedate); ?>;
```

with

```
var datestr = JSON.stringify(date);
alert(datestr);
```

It will convert the server response to a JSON encoded string. The encoded string is then displayed in the alert. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

Assign a global variable in HTML/PHP file before includeing JS file.

```
var datestr = <?php echo $thedate; ?>;
```

Then you can access the datestr variable from your JS file.